# What is the reasoning behind this combination question?

Tags: combinatorics

The full question text is below with answers and my reasoning for them. Could someone please explain the reasoning behind part (c).

> A coffee shop sells 5 types of coffee (latte, mocha, espresso, cappuccino and iced coffee). All coffee of the same type is indistinguishable. We are buying 10 coffees in total.
>
> How many ways are there to buy 10 coffees if:
>
> (a) there are no restrictions
>
> > C(10+5-1, 10)
> >     The reasoning is that given no restrictions, this is a combination with repetition.
>
> (b) you buy at least 2 iced coffees.
>
> > C(8+5-1, 8)
> >     The reasoning is that since 2 coffees are decided, its a combination with repetition for the remaining 8.
>
> (c) you can buy at most 2 mochas.
>
> > C(13,3) + C(12,3) + C(11,3)
> >     **Here is where I have no idea how they got these numbers.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can buy at most 2 mochas, you can either buy no mochas, 1 mocha or 2 mochas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you buy no mochas, it’s just like part (a), except that there are only four varieties, so the number of possibilities is $$\binom{10+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{13}3\;.$$ If you buy exactly one mocha, you’re making an unrestricted choice of the other nine from four varieties; you can do this in $$\binom{9+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{12}3$$ ways. Finally, if you buy exactly two mochas, you’re making an unrestricted choice of the other eight from four varieties; you can do this in $$\binom{8+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{11}3$$ ways.

Comment: edit cus i was being stupid. thank you.

Comment: @superdemongob: Happens to all of us. You’re welcome!

Comment: yea, i caught what i was missing a few seconds after i posted the comment asking about it... that was rather silly.